# Meteor: Iron-router render home page only after successful login

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have the following routes and only wish to perform Router.go('home'); AFTER a successful login.

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'Layout'});

Router.map(function(){
this.route('login', {path: '/'});
this.route('home', {path: '/home'});
this.route('posts', {path: '/posts'}); });
```

My layout template includes navbar which I don't want to show on the login page.

How can I GLOBAllY make this setting so that the if a user is not logged in, the page redirects the the 'login' template? I simply want to display my login template as it is whenever a user is not signed in.

Thank you in advance for contributing!

Comment: What package are you using for your login system?

Comment: I'm using accounts-base and accounts-password. The user logs in via Meteor.loginWithPassword

Comment: If you made your own ui I would `.render('loginTemplate')` similar to the answer @hubert-og provided, but replace `.redirect()`. That way uri are not lost and the process of going to the page never is interrupted. It depends on how you have your login system made. Some of the pre-packaged ones do not like to be rendered in a different route url. If you do use a package: `Router.go('route')` is what you want. And this could all vary depending on your ir version

Comment: This works! Thank you guys both! I replaced this.redirect from below with this.render

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will render 'signin' template on its own, in other words as a single page.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'master_layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
});

var OnBeforeActions;

OnBeforeActions = {
    loginRequired: function(pause) {
      if (!Meteor.userId()) {       
        Router.go('signin');
        return pause();
      }
    }
};
Router.onBeforeAction(OnBeforeActions.loginRequired, {
    except: ['signin']
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route('signin',{
        path: 'SignIn',
        layoutTemplate: 'signin'  // override main layout and use 'signin' templatate as main layout
    });

    this.route('notFound', {
    path: '*'
    });

});
```

Comment: This seems like it holds further control. Im testing it out and everything is running fine.

Comment: Add some 'signup' template to except var to let users access registration page without logging in.

Comment: Mark as solved and consider vote up if happy with the answer. Not just this but all the future posts.

Comment: When I have the credentials to vote, I will practice voting up.

Answer (score 0):

```
Router.configure({
  onBeforeAction: function(pause) {
    if(!Meteor.userId()) {
      this.redirect('login');
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Note: I'm not sure if this will work without `meteorhacks:fast-render` package. Try it, and if it redirects logged in users as well, add that package.

Comment: this does not work. Thank you, but I wish to find a method without a package because I understand there is a way but as iron router has updated, I'm unsure how to get this working.